# How can my guest, on her Mac, see my shared music library using "Share Music With Guests"?

Tags: macos, itunes, network, wifi, sharing

I have Home Sharing turned on, as well as "Share media with guests", with no password required.  This config is shown in the screenshots below.

[image: my home sharing / guest sharing config]

[image]

Both my Mac and my guests's Mac are connected to the same WiFi access point that I control at home.

- She cannot see my library in her Apple Music.
- For a little more context, I am a personal library user, do not use the Apple Music service, which is disabled in the app.

Are there steps to figure this out or fix the local sharing option in Music app?

Note: I do have Music running on my source laptop.

Comment: Do you have Music running? With the old iTunes, it had to be launched to be seen. idk for newer Music.

Comment: I do have Music running on my source laptop, yes...

Comment: Can both Macs see each other on your network? Can you check they're on the same subnet? Some routers intentionally split known users from guests so the guests cannot access the local network, only the internet.

Comment: My "guest" actually lives here and is connected to the router via the same credentials that I am.  She is only a "guest" in the sense of not sharing my Apple ID or being in my Apple "Family".

Answer (score 2):

Many routers prevent discovery between clients. A quick way to make sure it’s not the router configuration blocking discovery would be to connect your computers directly with an Ethernet cable or temporarily connect your Mac to the router with Ethernet and share your internet over wifi. Connect your guest computer to your wifi sharing on your Mac.

- https://support.apple.com/en-euro/guide/mac-help/mchlp1540/mac

You want to share Ethernet over wifi. Don’t try to connect to wifi and share out wifi per the warning to not try to connect and share over Ethernet. (Both pretty much guarantee you configure multiple DHCP servers on the same network segment)

Assuming the music sharing works over point to point network or sharing wifi, you’ll need the wifi network admin to fix things. If it doesn’t work, you might need to work on firewalls and why the second app doesn’t see your shared library.

- https://support.apple.com/en-euro/guide/music/muscadf6038/mac

---

As to the nitty gritty, on recent macOS with media sharing controlled from a system preference pane - you can choose a sharing name and see the service turn on and off in real time from any Mac on the network segment.

```
dns-sd -B _daap
```

When you're done press and hold the control key and while it's down, the C key once to exit the dns service delivery browse command.

[image: Home Sharing and Guest Sharing on macOS]

Home sharing uses the _home-sharing._tcp. service instead of _daap._tcp. that guest sharing does.

```
bmike@m1 ~ % dns-sd -B _daap
Browsing for _daap._tcp
DATE: ---Thu 30 Dec 2021---
10:33:46.256  ...STARTING...
Timestamp     A/R    Flags  if Domain               Service Type         Instance Name
10:33:46.257  Add        3   6 local.               _daap._tcp.          dev library
10:33:46.257  Add        2  12 local.               _daap._tcp.          dev library
```

Comment: Being my own WiFi admin here at home, might you know what I should tweak on my router?  Is this a Bonjour thing?

Comment: Yes @Marcus IGMP snooping and Bonjour / MDNS broadcast sections of the manual should be reviewed. Let me see if I can dig up a command line query to show you this working…

Comment: As it turns out, my guest CAN see my library from her Mac, using the `dns-sd -B _daap` command given above.  But how can she access my library from Music?  Nothing shows in there...

Comment: Did you click options in the panel shown above and select which songs can be seen? @Marcus I assumed by she can not see your library - she didn’t see the name you configured.

Comment: I added screenshots to the question so my config can be seen.  And that is correct, in her Music app on her Mac, my guest does not see my library name in the left hand panel or anywhere else.